# match words that appear at the beginning of the line in a table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Please take a look at this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cYFLe/124/)**. How would you make sure it only matches the occurrence of `Sodium` that appear at the beginning of the line in a table cell, for example :

`<td>Sodium</td>`, `<td>Sodium (from Kitchen Salt)</td>`

but not

`<td>Vitamin sodium</td>`,`<td>Fish Sodium</td>`

My attempt

```
`var find_Sodium = /^Sodium/ 
 alert($('.'+title+'table').find('td:contains(find_Sodium)').next().html());`
```

isn't working.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "url.json",
    success: function (data) {

        $(data.query.results.json.json).each(function (index, item) {     

            var title = item.title;
            var table = item.table; 
            if (table.indexOf("Sodium") >= 0) {

              $('.'+ title+'table').html(''+table+'');
              var find_Sodium = /^Sodium/;
              alert($('.'+title+'table').find('td:contains(find_Sodium)').next().html());

            }
        });
    },
    error: function () {}
});
```

Table Structure:

```
<table class="tablesorter">
<thead>
<tr>
<td>Ingredient</td>
<td>Amount</td>
<td>% Daily Value**</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Calories</td>
<td>10</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Sodium</td>
<td>2g</td>
<td>&lt;1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Vitamin C</td>
<td>110mg</td>
<td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Potassium sodium</td>
<td>235mg</td>
<td>6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Omega 6</td>
<td>1100mg</td>
<td>*</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Vitamin Sodium</td>
<td>1200mg</td>
<td>*</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Vitamin E</td>
<td>300mg</td>
<td>*</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:contains` does not accept a regex, the way to do this is to `filter()`

```
$('.'+title+'table').find('td').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().indexOf('Sodium') === 0;
}).next().html();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/cYFLe/126/)

using `indexOf === 0` makes sure Sodium has an index of zero, being the first thing to occur in the elements text